# Arithmetic which gives the lowest 64 bits on overflow

Tags: c, gcc, clang

In C unsigned integer arithmetic wraps around on overflow and signed arithmetic is undefined on overflow. I would like to have 64 bit integer arithmetic (+,-,*) so that on overflow the result is the lowest 64 bits.  Is this possible?

I don’t want a wrapped around result. What I am looking is equivalent to casting the integers to 128 bit types, performing the operation, taking the lowest 64 bits and casting back to the 64 bit type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the operands to the unsigned type (of the same size) first, perform the operation, then cast back to the signed type.

It's easy to prove for `+` and `-`. Wasn't certain about `*`, but it also seems to give the correct result.

---

GCC and Clang also have [`__builtin_{add,sub,mul}_overflow`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html), which always wrap around, and also report whether or not an overflow occured. They work with any integer type.

```
int a = 10, b = 20, result;
bool overflowed = __builtin_add_overflow(a, b, &result);
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I don’t want it to wrap around. The result I want is the lowest 64 bits of the true result. I’ll expand the question.

Comment: @Simd That is the same thing as wrapping around, I believe.

Comment: I didn’t realise that!

Comment: "cast back to the signed type" - do note that *technically* the result will be implementation defined if the unsigned value is out of range of the signed type. In practice, on twos-complement machines, you'll get the expected result, and in any case you won't get UB (but, the standard allows for an "implementation defined signal" to be raised).

Answer (score 2):

Unsigned integer arithmetic is defined to wrap. For w-bit integers, this means that computations (+, -, *) are performed modulo 2^w. This is exactly equivalent to always taking the low w bits of the result, and thus performing wrapped addition, subtraction, and multiplication is guaranteed to be mathematically correct in the low w bits. Thus, there is no need to perform computations with larger bit-widths if you only care about the low w bits of the result.

Signed integers are trickier. When converting a signed integer to an unsigned integer of the same width, a multiple of 2^w is added to bring the number into a representable range. In practice, for twos-complement machines, this means adding 2^w for negative numbers and 0 otherwise. Thus, converting a signed number to unsigned always preserves the value, modulo 2^w (even on non-twos-complement machines!).

Thus, if you take two signed integers, cast them to unsigned, then do the math, the resulting unsigned number will be equivalent to the signed result modulo 2^w. If you then convert this result back to a signed integer, you *should* get a value that is equal to the expected signed result; the use of unsigned arithmetic will avoid any undefined overflow.

Note the use of "should" in that last sentence. The tiny gotcha here is that, if the unsigned result is out of the range of the signed number's range (i.e. is >= 2^(w-1) on a twos-complement system), then converting that back to a signed integer is technically implementation-defined. In practice, since pretty much every machine these days is using twos-complement, the result will be what you expect.

Comment: The nice thing about two's complement machine actually is that not even bit patterns do change on converting signed to unsigned and vice versa, so this operation actually is free... To be noted, too: Sign possibly might not match expectations! Consider e.g. with four bits only `1100 * 0011 == 0100`: `-4 * 3 ≡ 4 mod 16` – which mathematically still is correct, albeit having expected a negative value...

Comment: We might do calculations modulo 2^63 instead and if need be adjust the sign by subtracting that value again – with four bits: `0b0100 ≡ 4 mod 8`, too, subtracting 8 gives -4 (`0b1100`) and still `-12 ≡ -4 mod 8` is mathematically correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

Extending on previous answers: While it is correct that wrapping around is simply calculating modulo 2<sup>64</sup> this calculation might end up with an unexpected sign! Consider four bits only:

```
1100 * 0011 = 10 0100 ≡ 0100 mod 10000
 12  *  3   =    36   ≡   4  mod   16
 -4  *  3             ≡   4  mod   16
```

Mathematically so far correct, but result of negative and positive integer is positive. On the one hand this *can* be used to detect overflow:

```
if((f1 ^ f2 & MSB) != (p & MSB))
{
    // overflow!
}
```

On the other hand you could adjust the sign as well:

```
1100 * 0011 = 10 0100 ≡  100  mod 1000
 12  *  3   =    36   ≡   4   mod  8
 -4  *  3             ≡   4   mod  8   // subtract 8!
 -4  *  3             ≡  -4   mod  8   // still correct!
1100 * 0011           ≡ 1100  mod 1000
```

Thus you can actually do:

```
#define MSB = ((uint64_t)1 << 63)

int64_t mul(int64_t x, int64_t)
{
    uint64_t p = (uint64_t)x * (uint64_t)y;
    p &= MSB;
    // subtracts MSB, if differing sign bits, else 0:
    p -= (uint64_t)x ^ (uint64_t)y & MSB;
    return p; // implicit conversion
}
```

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fn5a8nvW8) – and the drawback of this variant, right with it, too: While sign bit remains correct two values both small in absolute now can produce a value huge in absolute...

Leaving up to you which one is more desirable ;)